# NoClassDefFound Exception, when using imported jar from libs

Tags: android, jar, import, noclassdeffounderror, libs

I am trying referencing a **libs** folder in my project.

**1.)** I created a simple jar with one single dummy class `ImportableDummy.java` and exported the project as a jar.

**Jar Project:**

[image]

**2.)** Then I put the jar into the **libs folder** inside my Project.
The lib is then listed under "Private Libraries":

**Jar referencing Project:**

[image]
[image]

**3.)** 
At least I doublechecked, that the "PrivateLibraries" are marked as "exported"

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Still there is a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.my.ImportableDummy` exception, when I run the App. During compileTime the class is perfectly found by the compiler.

What am I missing?

- P.S. A tried to create a separate lib project for the jar too, with the same result.
- P.P.S. I started Eclipse with the `-clean` argument with no result

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the Jar was build with compiler 1.7

It should be **compiler 1.6** instead.

[image]